# Pass range into function

Tags: function, excel, range, parameter-passing, vba

I have the below code which i am using to ammend the command text of a query.
The issue is with the last line where I'm trying to pass a range (RepStartRng). Instead of passing the range address, my code is passing the range value. Please see below and thanks in advance.

```
Sub UseClass()
    Dim c As Report_
    Set c = New Report_

    Dim RepC As Long
    Dim Repcol As String
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim RepStartRng As Range

    c.Day = FindDay()
    Repcol = ColLetter(FindDay())
    RepC = CountReports(Repcol)
    c.name = "A"
    Debug.Print "Repcol: " & Repcol
    Debug.Print RepC
    c.RepCount = RepC
    For i = 1 To c.RepCount
        Counter = i
        Report = Rep(Counter, ColLetter(FindDay()))
        Set RepStartRng = Range(Repcol & "3")
        RepStartRng.Select
        Debug.Print RepStartRng.Address
        UpdateQuery Report, RepStartRng, Counter
    Next i
End Sub
Function UpdateQuery(Report As String, RepRng As Range, Counter As Long)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set RepRng = RepRng
    Dim Dat As String
    Dat = QueryDates(Rng)
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim NewWb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim odbcCn As ODBCConnection, oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        If cn.name = Report Then
            Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
            Debug.Print Dat
            oledbCn.CommandText = Replace(oledbCn.CommandText, "?", "'" & Dat & "'")
            Sheets(Rng.Value).Copy
            Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook
            NewWb.SaveAs ("C:\Users\krishn.patel\Desktop\" & Rng.Value & ".xlsb"), FileFormat:=50
            NewWb.Close
            oledbCn.CommandText = Replace(oledbCn.CommandText, "'" & Dat & "'", "?")
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: When you pass a range, you are passing the range object, not the address. Why do you think it is passing the value? What is the purpose of the line `Set RepRng = RepRng`. And why are you not using the range that you pass in (RepRng)?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of your range or seeing the other functions that you call (e.g. QueryDates), it is impossible to know if this code is perfect, but it should get you closer to what you need. I removed redundant variables and change the Function to a Sub since it returns no values.

```
Sub UseClass()
    Dim c As Report_
    Set c = New Report_

    Dim RepC As Long
    Dim Repcol As String
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim RepStartRng As Range

    c.Day = FindDay()
    Repcol = ColLetter(FindDay())
    RepC = CountReports(Repcol)
    c.name = "A"
    Debug.Print "Repcol: " & Repcol
    Debug.Print RepC
    c.RepCount = RepC
    For Counter = 1 To c.RepCount
        Report = Rep(Counter, ColLetter(FindDay()))
        Set RepStartRng = Range(Repcol & "3")
        UpdateQuery Report, RepStartRng, Counter
    Next Counter
End Sub
Sub UpdateQuery(Report As String, RepRng As Range, Counter As Long)
    Dim Dat As String
    Dat = QueryDates(RepRng)
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim NewWb As Workbook

    Dim odbcCn As ODBCConnection, oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        If cn.name = Report Then
            Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
            Debug.Print Dat
            oledbCn.CommandText = Replace(oledbCn.CommandText, "?", "'" & Dat & "'")
            Sheets(RepRng.Value).Copy
            Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook
            NewWb.SaveAs ("C:\Users\krishn.patel\Desktop\" & RepRng.Value & ".xlsb"), FileFormat:=50
            NewWb.Close
            oledbCn.CommandText = Replace(oledbCn.CommandText, "'" & Dat & "'", "?")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```